# Deleting original files as you go along adding files to a TAR file

Tags: python-3.x, tar

I've written a small server function which is intended to `tar` together a bunch of locally downloaded files, then delete the originals. It looks something like this:

```
with tarfile.open(archive_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
    for pb in designated_objects:
        bucket.download_file(pb.key, pb.key)
        tar.add(pb.key)
        os.delete(pb.key)
```

My expectation is that this will generate a tarfile with all of my desired data and an otherwise empty directory. The idea here is that I would like to minimize my disc usage as much as possible. However, I'm unsure if deleting a file before the tarfile is finished being generated (as done here) is allowed.

Will this expression work as expected?

If it will not, is there something akin to an append mode that will?

Comment: seems like the simplest way to find out would be to just try it

Comment: Is this for an AWS s3 bucket? Have you considered using [`download_fileobj`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_fileobj) instead? That way you won't have to bother putting duplicate data on-disk just to delete it moments later.

Comment: @sytech This is indeed an AWS S3 operation. I'm impressed you've caught onto it! And it's a Lambda function that I'm trying to optimize memory usage on.

Comment: @dave I did try it. See the answer below.

Comment: @AlekseyBilogur then using `download_fileobj` sounds like the way to go. Because `tarfile.open` accepts file-like objects, you should be able to download the file directly into your archive without putting it on-disk intermediately.

Comment: I may go back to that approach. But at the moment the simplest solution for my use-case seems to be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086722/downloading-pattern-matched-entries-from-s3-bucket actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, the original files are populated, then deleted. However, the behavior of the archive is unusual. When this code block is run, *no* archive is generated. In fact, this code block will do nothing at all (except delete your files).

I find this behavior particularly unusual and surprising given the fact that taking a `pass` inside the `with` statement (as in the code that follows) will actually write an empty archive to disc. So in a sense, the given code block does *even less than nothing*!

```
with tarfile.open('archive_filename.xy.gz', "w:gz") as tar:
   pass
```

For reference, this behavior is what I get with Python 3.6. Behavior with other versions of Python may differ.