# How to copy file while preserving directory structure using AWS command line

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, unix, amazon-s3, rsync

I have the following directory in my local computer:

```
dir1
  |
  |__ randomfile.jpg
  |__ dir2
        |
        |__ file1.txt
        |__ file2.txt
        |__ pict.png
```

What I want to do is to copy all the files with `*.txt` and preserving the subdirectory structure to [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket. How can I do that?

At the end of the day in S3. We'd like to find this file and directory structure:

```
 dir1
      |
      |__ dir2
            |
            |__ file1.txt
            |__ file2.txt
```

With standard Unix command I can do this:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec cp --parents \{\} /target \;
```

But not sure how to do with with [AWS command line.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/index.html#cli-aws)

In reality with have files with ~10Tb of size to transfer.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659382/downloading-an-entire-s3-bucket

Answer (score 8):

Just use sync:

```
aws s3 sync src/ s3://mybucket --exclude "*" --include "*.txt"
```

[Exclude include doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Comment: As an alternative to `sync` (which is intended for repeated syncing), you could use `aws s3 cp --recursive ...` which would do the same job.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you could but exclude and include as of now work only with sync and not with cp or mv!

Comment: @KaranShah that works with `cp` you need ` --recursive`

Comment: @Ôrel recursive will copy everything, it cannot exclude the random file as mentioned in the question

Comment: My point is exclue and include are supported by cp, but here to keep structure you need sync I agree