# Data Migration from AWS to IBM Cloud

Tags: amazon-s3, migration, cloud, ibm-cloud

We want to migrate AWS S3 buckets (10 TB) to IBM Cloud Storage and AWS RDS for MySQL to IBM Cloud- Compose for MySQL (5 GB). What are the possible approaches?

Answer (score 1):

For your MySQL migration you can use MySQL workbench to export your AWS hosted MySQL database to a backup file(s) on your local machine, then import the backup file to the new IBM hosted MySQL server.

In MySQLWorkbench connect to the AWS server > Click Server at the top > Data Export > Check your db > Check Export to Self-Contained File > Check Include Create Schema > Start Export

Connect to the IBM server > Create a DB with the same name as the original > Click Server at the top > Data Import > Check Import from Self-Contained File > Start Import

To migrate your S3 buckets, copy the buckets to your local system using the AWS CLI or CyberDuck.  See a variety of ways at [Downloading an entire S3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659382/downloading-an-entire-s3-bucket)

Then upload the files to your IBM Cloud Storage.  Here are some ways to do so https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/basics/upload.html#uploading-data

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [rclone](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_sync/) that can be used for syncing data between cloud storages. Once set up it can be used as:

`rclone sync source:path dest:path [flags]`

IBM Documentation has [instructions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/cli?topic=cloud-object-storage-rclone) on how to install and use it as well.